# Can I with fzaninotto/Faker generate doc / xls files?

Tags: faker

Reading docs for laravel 9 site at
https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker
I did not find if there is a way to generate doc(microsoft word) / xls(microsoft excel)  files with this library ?
Maybe some other library ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Faker is using to generate simple data like sentences, email, phone etc. But you can use, for example `maatwebsite/excel` to make xlsx filling it with faker.
The simplest way to create `doc` file is to make `html` file with `doc` extension.

**Update:**

Keep in mind that `maatwebsite/excel` was built for Laravel framework, but there are other packages witch can be used independent from frameworks, for example [XLSWriter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xlswriter.php)

### maatwebsite/excel

Laravel's factory to make User model

```php
class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = User::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'login' => '0'.$this->faker->numberBetween(70000000000, 80000000000),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'lastname' => $this->faker->lastName,
            'firstname' => $this->faker->firstNameMale,
            'phone' => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
        ];
    }
}
```

maatwebsite's export class (this one uses a collection as source)

```php
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    private $collection;

    public function __construct($collection)
    {
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }
}
```

Make xlsx file with 10 users uses laravel's seeder

```php
class XlsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $users = User::factory()
            ->count(10)
            ->make();
        Excel::store(new UsersExport($users), 'users.xlsx');
    }
}
```

### XLSWriter

Wherever you need to create xlsx, you can write something like:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $users[] = [
        $faker->numberBetween(70000000000, 80000000000),
        $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        $faker->lastName,
        $faker->firstName,
        $faker->phoneNumber,
    ];
}

$fileObject  = new \Vtiful\Kernel\Excel([
        'path' => './tests'
    ]);

$file = $fileObject->fileName('users.xlsx', 'sheet_one')
    ->header(['login', 'email', 'lastname', 'firstname', 'phone'])
    ->data($users);

$file->output();
```

Comment: Could you please give example?